# How to print Exception name only?

Tags: java, exception

```
try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = input.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException g) {
    System.out.println(g);
}
```

When user insert `"2147483648"` as an input to `x` , `java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "2147483648"` Exception is printed. But I need to print `java.util.InputMismatchException` only. How to do that?

Comment: System.out.println("java.util.InputMismatchException");

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What use is knowing just the exception name?

Comment: Hackerrank problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
System.out.println(g);
```

with

```
System.out.println(g.getClass().getName());
```